# Apache 301 redirection from one domain to another

Tags: server, apache2

I'm trying to set a redirection in my VirtualHost configuration for my website. So far I am able to redirect non www trafficto the www address like this :

```
<VirtualHost: *:80>
    ServerAlias www.gcbeauce.com
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^guidedescommercesdebeauce\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.guidedescommercesdebeauce.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

But what I also want is to redirect the old domain to this new one. I have tried adding :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^guidedescommercesdebeauce\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^gcbeauce\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.guidedescommercesdebeauce.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

But nothing happens.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: While your machine might be running Ubuntu, an Apache question like this one might get a better result on serverfault.com.

Answer (score 1):

You need to negate the match. Try this:

```
RewriteCond ${HTTP_HOST} !^www\.guidedescommercesdebeauce\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.guidedescommercesdebeauce.com$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

Notice the exclamation mark in the `RewriteCond`. Note also that this will force a single canonical domain name. I'm assuming this is what you want. If not, then you'll have to enumerate the domain names to be redirected. In that case, be sure to add `[OR]` to the end of the `RewriteCond`.

I've also added `[QSA]` to your flags. That way, any query string that might exist will be preserved.

Finally, you are *strongly urged* to read the mod_rewrite documentation carefully, as it has answers to this and many other questions.

Answer (score 0):

Missing a slash before $1?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.new-domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Adding the extra slash will make the url looks like : http://new-domain.com//something in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Apache 2.4 ,without the need to enable the rewrite apache module you can use something like this:

```
# old-domain.com to new-domain.com
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} = 'old-domain.com'">
  Redirect 301 "/" "http://new-domain.com/"
</If>
```